# Replace Microsoft sculpt. TKL, wireless and programmable

Tags: keyboards

So I'm looking for a new keyboard to replace my Microsoft sculpt ergonomic. I really like the sculpt but before the sculpt I had an other Microsoft ergonomic keyboard where one could remap the left spacebar to be backspace. This is such an underestimated feature on ergonomic keyboards!

Best candidates so far:
Microsoft sculpt (missing my key feature otherwise perfect), Logitech ergo K860 (missing my key feature, wireless), Matias ergo pro programmable (separate pieces, not wireless, programmable).

Requirements

- Ergonomic
- programmable split spacebar

Big plus otherwise

- wireless (moved from req. to simplify)
- separate numpad (this is probably very unusual, )
- One piece (not like matias or ergodox so I can have it in my lap)
- quiet
- TKL (since I mostly do officework I want the mouse closer to the center)

Mechanical or not doesn't matter.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for posterity, I went with the X-bows Natural. It is not wireless and doesn't have a separate numpad. There is a more expensive one with this feature. I've flashed the center backspace key to be delete and the left spacebar to be backspace. The process is easy with videos on X-bows website explaining how to do it.

It needs some getting used to but this seems like a good fit for me. I get the feeling that the keyboard actually forces me to be more correct with how I type since the columnar layout makes it stranger to not use the correct fingers for typing.

The keyboard is mechanical with silent brown switches. There is also backlighting.